# abrir link externo webview

Tags: android, webview, intent

Tenho uma app webview que é feito 100% do webview, porém quero abrir alguns links fora do app, por exemplo, os links que começam com intent, no caso quero colocar um botão no site que abre um app, mas ta tentando abrir dentro do webview e está dando erro, então tem que fazer abrir fora dele... como fazer ?

Comment: Você quer que o link abra uma aplicação no dispositivo Android?

Comment: isso, fiz um site, ai coloquei ele no webview.. e nele tem um a href com intent, quero que qndo clica nesse ahref com intent abra uma pagina externa e fazendo isso ele vai abrir o app

Comment: Veja https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei o seguinte código em um menu de contexto numa lista, ele usa o navegador padrão do usuário. talvez ele possa ajudar um pouco para adapta-lo em um botão.

```
    MenuItem itemSite = menu.add("Visitar Site");
    Intent intentSite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //coloca o https na frente
    String site = suaURL;
    if (!site.startsWith("http://")) {
        site = "http://" + site;
    }
    //seta o site
    intentSite.setData(Uri.parse(site));
    itemSite.setIntent(intentSite);
```